# Git: simulate octopus merge using multiple single ref merges

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I know I can trigger an octopus merge using `git merge ref1 ref2`, but is it also possible to get the same result using multiple commands, e.g.

```
git merge --no-commit ref1
git merge --no-commit --magic-option ref2
git commit
```

or after

```
git merge ref1
git merge ref2
```

turn the last 2 merge commits into 1 octopus merge commit?

Comment: Note that `git merge-octopus` uses a different merge base computation and refuses to do merges that would require conflict resolution, so that no matter how you do this, you won't necessarily get the *same* result as by using `git merge` with multiple hash-or-branch-names or `git merge -s octopus`. But mostly, see [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59161723/1256452).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do separate merges, and then create a new merge revision with `git commit-tree`... so.. something like this:

```
git checkout --detach brancha # so that the branch doesn't move
git merge branchb -m "Whatever"
git merge branchc -m "Whatever again"
# now we do our magic
git checkout $( git commit-tree -m "Here's the octopus merge" -p brancha -p branchb -p branchc HEAD^{tree} )
# last command creates a new revision with brancha branchb and branchc as parents, will hold the tree of the last merge.. and we check it out
# if you like it, you can move any of the branches and then check it out
git branch -f brancha
git checkout brancha
```